# Stopping a for loop with a button

Tags: java, multithreading, button

I am trying to stop a `for` loop that is initiated by pressing a button. The only problem I have found is that the application is literally non-responsive once the start button is pressed. How would I go about making the stop button? At the moment the only way I can stop the application outside of my IDE is to go into task manager and forcibly delete it.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
String L = "Hello";
int Num = Integer.parseInt(m1.getText());
int Num2 = Integer.parseInt(m2.getText());
nu = Num;  
for (int kk = nu; nu > 0; nu--) {
    if (O1.isSelected()) {
        for (int num3 = nu; nu > 0; nu--) {
            try {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Num2 * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }                                        
    }
}
```

This is the code I have, I have been looking around and I think I need to use the SwingWorker class. I am not sure how to implement it though.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with Java naming conventions.  Local variables should not be defined beginning with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put your loop inside the button action handler?

If so remove it and put it in a thread. Else it will block the EDT and app will become unresponsive. Use buttons only to trigger start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is hard to determine, but you are probably performing the loop on AWT thread, hence your UI is blocked and you can not press a button.

You should move your endless loop to another Thread, and then the button will work

Answer (score 0):

You are entering in an infinite loop any how. I would suggest to put your loop in a separate thread and when you want to stop it just interrupt that thread on button click.

Answer (score 0):

**Move the code into a dedicated thread and use a variable check to end the loop externally.**

The first problem is that you're performing this loop inside the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  This is a thread which is dedicated to handling the user interface.  Since you are looping and sleeping in this thread, it is unavailable to handle any other user interactions.  So effectively you are locking yourself out of your own program.

The proper way to shut this down is to create a `shutdown()` method on the loop which will modify a variable that is checked in each iteration of the loop.  Then, when you want to shut it down, you just call this method on the `Runnable` and the loop shuts down.

```
public class KeyPressRunnable implements Runnable {
    private boolean isRunning = true;

    public void shutdown() {
        this.isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // put your loop in here, and include this code in the loop:
        if (!this.isRunning) break;
    }
}
```